# VS Code Python: unable to get auto import suggestions

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code on Linux. [Auto imports](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_enable-auto-imports) do not work for me.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing "No code actions available" on "math"]

However, if I `import math`, VS Code is able to give suggestions when I type `math.`. This is my user settings.json:

```json
{
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": false,
    "python.analysis.indexing": true,
    "python.analysis.autoImportCompletions": true,
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "-vv"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": -2
}
```

I don't have anything in my workspace settings.json. I've installed the ms-python and ms-pyright extensions. Everything should be a relatively recent version. Any ideas?

Comment: According to that documentation, auto-import will offer _suggestions_ for import statements; it does not actually _perform_ the import for you.  And I see that you have deliberately ignored the suggestion by commenting-out the `import math` statement, so ... I don't know what your actual question is.

Comment: Are you using Pylance?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Pylance. The expected behavior when I press Ctrl-. is a dropdown menu that suggests `math` to be imported.

Comment: Actually, I don't think I am using Pylance. When I try to set `python.languageServer` to "Pylance", I get 

```
The Pylance extension is not installed but the python.languageServer value is set to "Pylance". Would you like to install the Pylance extension to use Pylance, or revert back to Jedi?
```

Comment: Seems like attempting to install the Pylance extension doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was not using Pylance (despite thinking I was). I manually installed a Pylance vsix file [from the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance).

I thought I was using Pylance because the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) says it will automatically install Pylance and given I didn't change any default settings, I assumed it was on. This was incorrect (though I'm not sure why).

Comment: Are you actually using VSCodium or some other Code-OSS distro? I don't know why else you'd need to install Pylance manually.

Comment: One thing to mention is I installed VS Code from Arch Linux AUR: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/visual-studio-code-bin